# validate a user input against multiple unique constraint in a database

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma, server-side-validation

I am trying to do a server side validation of a signup input
I am using nestjs with prisma and postgresql
i receive the request body as two filds for example

```js
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsString, IsMobilePhone} from "class-validator";

export class EmailSigninDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    @isMobilePhone()
    phoneNumber: string;
}
```

after validating the request body i try to add the new user
the probleme is: in my postgresql database these to fields must be unique and i cant find a way to validate two field at once

what i tried to do is the following
i try to create a new record with the requested email and phoneNunber and if the two already exists prisma throws an error which i can catch using nestjs exception filter **BUT** Pisma throws and error containin only the first field which violate the unique constraint so i have to tell the client the email is already in use and the client might send an other request containing a different email but with the same phoneNumber which also violated the unique constraint

i thought about making two queries where i check if there is a user with PhoneNumber and email but i think there might be a better solution

PS: i am new to backend developement and this is my first time using a database